# Selecting IDs with numbers within a range

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am currently working on something that requires me to select multiple SVG elements at a time. Each one of these SVG elements has an id: "person" + some number ranging from 0 to about 3000. During certain points, I would want to select a range of SVG elements at once for a transition animation.

I currently have this implemented with a for loop, however this seems to take too long and cause the transition animation to lag.

Is there a way to do a selectAll on SVG items that have the IDs within a range? Example: person1 - person3?

```
<div>
  <rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person0"></rect>
  <rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person1"></rect>
  <rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person2"></rect>
  <rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person3"></rect>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the selection code with its surrounding context, the markup is not very useful here.

Comment: I added the fact there is a surrounding div but the question is more of a general one of if there is a way to do a selectAll for elements with ID's that are only different based off a number at the end.

Comment: No, there is not. There will be a DOM search for every id. Cache all the elements into an array (or in a jQuery object) and apply Shouyeb's answer. You won't need ids at all, if all the elements are wrapped in a particular parent element.

Comment: What is the logic for how parts of the SVG / or the SVGs are selected? It may help us provide a better direction. I'd want to have them all share a class or something... but maybe your use-case has a reason?

Comment: @njfy410 you asked in both the question body and in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604642/selecting-ids-with-numbers-within-a-range#comment97904636_55604642) if there is a way to do this using `selectAll`, but at the same time you put a [tag:jquery] tag. I'm confused: do you want to do this with D3 or not?

Comment: Maybe you can show us an example of what you want to happen - https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/vkhndo6y/

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem: "I have this with a for loop, however this seems to take too long and cause the transition animation to lag." - are you *sure* it's the select-by-id that's taking too long? It's more likely that you're adding animation *within the loop* instead of in bulk, which will cause animation to lag, not the act of selecting by id.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/), if you want to avoid for loop.

```
var rects = $( "rect" ).slice( 1, 4 );
console.log(rects);
```

Gives you person1 - person3 in rects.

Comment: each is a loop though

Answer (score 1):

The first logical choice would be using CSS attribute selectors with a regex. However, CSS does not support regex in selectors (as far as I know).

So, another choice is using `d3.range` to create the range of IDs, like this...

```
d3.range(first ID value, last ID value + 1, 1).map(d=>"#person" + d).join(",")
```

... which you can pass to `selectAll`, as you asked in the question:

> Is there a way to do a selectAll on SVG items that have the IDs within a range?

Here is a demo:

```js
const start = 3;
const stop = 7;
d3.selectAll(d3.range(start, stop + 1, 1).map(d=>"#person" + d).join(","))
 .style("fill", "wheat")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect x="5" y="10" width="10" height="50" id="person0"></rect>
  <rect x="25" y="10" width="10" height="50" id="person1"></rect>
  <rect x="45" y="10" width="10" height="50" id="person2"></rect>
  <rect x="65" y="10" width="10" height="50" id="person3"></rect>
  <rect x="85" y="10" width="10" height="50" id="person4"></rect>
  <rect x="105" y="10" width="10" height="50" id="person5"></rect>
  <rect x="125" y="10" width="10" height="50" id="person6"></rect>
  <rect x="145" y="10" width="10" height="50" id="person7"></rect>
  <rect x="165" y="10" width="10" height="50" id="person8"></rect>
  <rect x="185" y="10" width="10" height="50" id="person9"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps thanks

```js
var range = '2-6';//say
range = range.split('-')
for(var i=range[0];i<=range[1];i++)
{
  console.log($("#person"+i+"").attr('id'))

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person0"></rect>
<rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person1"></rect>
<rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person2"></rect>
<rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person3"></rect>
<rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person4"></rect>
<rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person5"></rect>
<rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person6"></rect>
```

Comment: I already have something like this. I was wondering if there was a way to do it without a for loop in order to make the selection faster.

Comment: @njfy410 - this is why you should be showing _your_ code

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery `filter()` and regex

`^person[1-3]$`

- `^` - start of a line
- `person` - matches the characters person literally (case sensitive)

  - `[1-3]` - range between 1 and 3

```js
let $rect = $('rect')
              .filter(function() {
                return this.id.match(/^person[1-3]$/)
              })
              
console.log($rect.get())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person0"></rect>
  <rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person1"></rect>
  <rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person2"></rect>
  <rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person3"></rect>
  <rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person4"></rect>
  <rect x="5" y="52" width="5" height="5" id="person5"></rect>
</div>
```